# Make HTTPS request on Android with Volley

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley

I have installed a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on my server. What are the required steps to perform an HTTPS request from my Android app using Volley. This is my current code:

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = getString(R.string.server_url);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("imgUrl", mEdit.getText().toString());
            params.put("token", userIdToken);

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

What should i add to this code?

Comment: Are you facing any issue/exception?

Comment: No. I am just asking if i need to change my code in order for the POST request to be encrypted/secured or if adding 'https' to the url is enough.

Comment: "https" is enough. Volley will take care of it as it uses `HttpURLConnection` under the hood. Refer https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample

Comment: Thank you for your help!